# JMS Subscribe message in Gatling 3.9

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have been looking for the solution to consume JMS messages in gatling. As per the documentation, JMS in gatling only support requestreply or send. There is no option for consume messages only.

Is it possible with latest version of gatling or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not documented, it doesn't exist. Contributions or sponsoring welcome.